# Why did Sentinel Prime betray Ironhide?

Tags: transformers, transformers-live-action-series, transformers-dark-of-the-moon

In *Dark of the Moon*, we see that Sentinel Prime is good at the first half of the film. But at the near climax, Sentinel Prime betrays Ironhide. As we see in the movie, Sentinel Prime is an Autobot - and yet he agreed with Megatron to resurrect Cybertron.

Why did he change his allegiance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why?

### For Cybertron!

It looks like that the Autobots consider Earth their new home, and they don't want to rebuild Cybertron. Decepticons, instead, want to rebuild Cybertron. Sentinel's love for his home planet overcomes his loyalty to his fellows Autobots. He explains it in the movie (even if I acknowledge that dialogues often get lost between Bay's beloved explosions):

> Optimus: Why, Sentinel, why?
>
> Sentinel: For Cybertron! For our home! What war destroyed, we can rebuild! But only if we join with the Decepticons.
>
> Optimus: No, it’s not the only way. This is our home! We must defend the humans!
>
> Sentinel: So lost you are, Optimus. On Cybertron, we were gods. And here, they call us machines. Let the humans serve us, or perish.

Autobots consider humans their new friends, which apparently Sentinel can't accept, because he considers them weak. So he probably considers weak also the Autobots, and so he allies with the one he considers stronger: Megatron.

### But wait, there's more!

I don't remember if it is explained in the movie (you know, "BOOM > dialogue") but according to the wiki (take the wiki with a grain of salt, as usual!) Sentinel [betrayed the Autobots many years ago](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Sentinel_Prime_(Transformers_Film_Series)), when he fled from the dying Cybertron. So he decided to double-cross his allies even before setting foot on Earth, what happened on Earth later (Autobots friends with humans) only made him angrier and his betrayal more vehement.

p.s. Sentinel [is not the only one that changed side](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64466/have-any-autobots-changed-sides-to-the-decepticons) in the Transformers franchise, so his betrayal is not so "strange".

Comment: I like pretty much everything about this answer (last paragraph most). +1 from me, good job!

Comment: I have only one quirrel with the answer. That Sentinel did it for cybertron. In the film he states it himself a few times that he wants to be regarded as god. And as prime does not share his vision he will be the ONLY god there is. Thus it is not for cybertron...that is only an excuse imho, but instead he is as powerhungry as the next decepticon and was never worth the autobot symbol.

Comment: @Thomas, maybe I should rethink my answer...

Answer (score 0):

In short... because Ironhide was in his way, and with Optimus not there, there was no one there with the firepower to stop him.

In long:
Sentinel betrayed the Autobot cause a very very long time ago on Cybertron. He was a traitor already back then. The thing I don't understand is why Starscream destroyed the arc with him, but that could have been a double cross there.

Still though, Sentinel with what he said his motives were sounded more like a Decepticon than an Autobot (he wanted to be a god again... and he was only eager to share so far as he had to).

With Optimus not at the base, and Sentinel needing the contained artifacts from there for his plan to work, he only had to convert or get rid of the Autobots there. And as Autobots usually are loyal... it was clear that it would be better to eliminate them in a surprise strike. So he killed Ironhide (according to what I read he even killed the "twins" from *Transformers 2*). And also anyone who stood in his way.

So all in all... no surprise betrayal if someone knows the truth, but more sort of an ambush by a camouflaged (as Autobot) enemy. And Ironhide just stood in the way.